# Integer overflow in greedy coin counting

Tags: c, greedy, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) { 

    printf ("Enter amount: ");
    float amount = GetFloat();
    int coins = 0;

    while (amount != 0) {

        if (fmod(amount, 0.25) == 0) {
            amount = amount - 0.25;
            coins += 1;
        }

        else if (fmod(amount, 0.10) == 0) {
            amount = amount - 0.10;
            coins += 1;
        }

        else if (fmod(amount, 0.05) == 0) {
            amount = amount - 0.05;
            coins += 1;
        }

        else {
            amount = amount - 0.01;
            coins += 1;
        }
    }

    printf ("Coins : %d\n", coins);
}
```

I'm trying to implement a small greedy algorithm, in which a user inputs an amount of money ( Ex: 9.25 ) and we output the least amount of coins that it takes for us to exchange it in change( 25 cents, 10 cents, 5 cents and 1 cent only).

This algorithm works with int amounts like 10 or 20 and with amounts that only requires the program to use the 25 cents coins.

If I try an amount like 9.10 or 9.01, I get a runtime error, signed integer overflow. I understand what it means, but I don't understand how can the value of coins go so high all of a sudden.

Comment: Multiply it by 100 and do it like with integers

Comment: I tried this version and it gives the same error, works with integer numbers and numbers that end in .25, anything else doesnt work.

Comment: I tried running your code for `9.01`. It works fine. Gives `37` coins as ouput.

Comment: I used `scanf` instead of `GetFloat()`.

Comment: Weird, coming from python and ruby, everything is so arcane in C. I've used GetFloat because thats what the harvad course that i'm taking is suggestin us to use, i didn't understand why they wouldn't just use scanf, maybe because he didn't cover pointers yet?

Comment: Have you tried it with `scanf`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken   and  http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Allen You know Python and Ruby are written primarily in C, right? So they do this under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

As Danial Tran said it is better to use int when you do logical operations. Please read  [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) Also you can avoid while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) { 

    printf ("Enter amount: ");
    //float amount = GetFloat(); //Please refer to chqrlie's comments below.
    double amount  = 0.0;
    scanf("%lf",&amount); //I don't know GetFloat() equivalent for double. So using scanf().

    long long int amountInt = (long long int) (amount * 100.0);

    int coins = 0;

    if (25 <= amountInt) {
        coins += (amountInt/25);
        amountInt = amountInt % 25;
    }

    if (10 <= amountInt) {
        coins += (amountInt/10);
        amountInt = amountInt % 10;
    }

    if (5 <= amountInt) {
        coins += (amountInt/5);
        amountInt = amountInt % 5;
    }

    if (1 <= amountInt) {
        coins += amountInt;
    }

    printf ("Coins : %d\n", coins);
}
```

Comment: It fails for `100.10`: returns 400 quarters, 1 nickel and 4 pennies.

Comment: @chqrlie, Yes. I printed amount and it was giving 100.099998. I modified my code to handle this type of errors. Could you please try one more time?

Comment: Yes, but `1000000.10` returns 4 million quarters, 1 dime and 3 extra pennies `-;)`

Comment: Rounding with `int amountInt = (int)(amount * 100 + 0.5);` is much simpler.

Comment: I tried this. It is giving same problem when input is 1000000.10. I printed float value for 1000000.10, 1000000.11, 1000000.12. They are all stored as 1000000.125000. So it is better to change input to two integer values: dollars and cents.

Comment: No, it is better to use `double` and `long long int`. Changing the user interface to account for a technical difficulty is an engineer's temptation you must resist.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is not correct:

For example with 30 cents you can exchange to: 25+5 (2 coins) with your algorithm it would be 10+10+10 (3 coins). So greedy means why it's greater than 25 cents then exchange to 25 cents first.

```
while (amount != 0) {

    if (amount >= 0.25) {
        amount = amount - 0.25;
        coins += 1;
    }

    else if (amount >= 0.10) {
        amount = amount - 0.10;
        coins += 1;
    }

    else if (amount >= 0.05) {
        amount = amount - 0.05;
        coins += 1;
    }

    else {
        amount = amount - 0.01;
        coins += 1;
    }
}
```

If you want to do that way.

Better way:

```
int coinTypes[] = {0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01};

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   coins += floor(amount / coinTypes[i];
   amount -= coins * coinsTypes[i];
}
```

Comment: You did not explain why his algorithm is incorrect, and why yours isn't.

Comment: I understand now, mine if it were to work correctly and if for example had an input like 1.20, it would skip the 25 cents coins, and go to the 10 cents and back to the 25 cents again and output 10 coins, even though there was a better way of giving change(7 coins is the correct answer).

Comment: *int coinTypes[] = {0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01};* will initalize all values to `0`, dividing `amount` by `0` will yield `Infinity`, converting that to `int` invokes undefined behavior (C11 6.3.1.4).  If you make the array `float`, you will still experience the precision issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that no one has answered the particular question

> If i try an amount like 9.10 or 9.01, i get a runtime error,signed integer overflow, i understand what it means, but i don't understand how can the value of coins go so high all of a sudden.

so for the sake of completeness, partially as an exercise:

You can find the reason using a **debugger**. I copied your code and found that it runs for very long. Interrupting it a moment after start revealed that the code freezes repeating this check:

```
if (fmod(amount, 0.25) == 0) {
    amount = amount - 0.25;
    coins += 1;
}
```

At the moment of the interruption `amount` was about minus 1.2 million and coins almost 5 million. This clearly shows one thing you failed to check: negativity. It can happen easily with floats that you miss the *exact* zero, as the others have correctly reasoned, no need to repeat that. But if that happens, your program should get worried the moment `amount` gets negative. Otherwise, under the right conditions, it may as well keep subtracting its way towards negative infinity, and yes, integer overflow will happen in `coins`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the computer represent the decimals in **binary** (power of 2)

For 0.25, the computer can represent it properly in binary. This is because **we can obtain 0.25 exactly using power of 2**'s.

However for 0.10 ( or other denominations mentioned ), they cannot be expressed exactly in powers of 2.

Suppose you try to obtain 0.1 using power of 2's , you won't be able to obtain it exactly. You can just go near it.

0.1 = 0.0625 ( 2^4 ) +  0.03125 ( 2^5 ) + 0.00390625 ( 2^-8) +...

You will approach 0.1 , but you'll never reach 0.1 exactly.

Float, double everyone has a fixed number of bits to represent a decimal. So it will keep only those many bits, whose sum would be slightly less than 0.1

If you want to follow the same approach, you can have 2 possible solutions :-

> 1. Use **(amount > 0)** instead of **(amount != 0)**, or
> 2. Use currencies which can be expressed easily in **powers of 2** e.g. 0.25, 0.125 , 0.375 , 0.06125.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your algorithm is invalid usage of `fmod` function. According to definition the result of `fmod(num, denom)` is

```
fmod = num - floor(num/denom) * denom
```

where `floor(num/denom)` is integer.
Thus, `fmod(9.10, 0.25) == 0.1`, `fmod(9.10, 0.10) == 0.1`.

In addition, the manipulation with floating point number rarely gives exact results. so `amount` is never `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compute this with the `float` type.  Amounts that are not exact multiples of 0.25 cannot be represented exactly in either the `float` or the `double` type.

You can fix this problem by computing an exact number of cents and dispatch it using integer arithmetics:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void print_coins(int coins, const char *singular, const char *plural) {
    if (coins > 0)
        printf(" %d %s", coins, coins > 1 ? plural : singular);
}

int main(void) {
    for (;;) {
        double amount;
        int amountInt, coins, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;

        printf("Enter amount: ");
        if (scanf("%lf", &amount) != 1 || amount <= 0)
            break;

        amountInt = (int)(amount * 100.0 + 0.5);

        quarters = amountInt / 25;
        amountInt %= 25;
        dimes = amountInt / 10;
        amountInt %= 10;
        nickels = amountInt / 5;
        amountInt %= 5;
        pennies = amountInt;
        amountInt = 0;

        coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

        printf("coins returned: %d:", coins);
        print_coins(quarters, "quarter", "quarters");
        print_coins(dimes, "dime", "dimes");
        print_coins(nickels, "nickel", "nickels");
        print_coins(pennies, "penny", "pennies");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- Using `float` without the `+ 0.5`, the change is incorrect for as little as `100.10`: one penny short.
- Using `float`, the change is incorrect for `1000000.10`: 3 extra pennies.
- To handle amounts above 20 million dollars, you need a larger integral type such as `long long int`.  With that, you can handle amounts exceeding the US national debt.